# Unable to remove cookie in play framework 1.2.4

Tags: cookies, playframework-1.x

I am using play 1.2.4.
I have set a cookie and I am fetching the cookie using the below code --

```
    @Util
    public static void setCookie(String name, String value) {
        // Setting cookie
        response.setCookie(name, value);
    }

    public static Http.Cookie getCookie(String key) {
        // retrieving cookie by key
        return request.cookies.get(key);
    }
```

and I am using the below code to remove the cookie --

```
public static void removeCookie(String key) {
        // removing cookie by key
        request.cookies.remove(key);
    }
```

but the cookie is not getting removed.

Please suggest where am I going wrong?

N.B. - All the above codes are written in **Application.java** and I am calling the function from another controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use

```
response.removeCookie(key);
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove cookie be sure that you have already included play.mvc.Http.Cookie & play.mvc.Http.Request jar files.
You can use this command to remove it.

> response().discardCookie("name of cookie");